# How to iterate array of json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

In my scrip I read array of json from POST param like this `$data = $_POST["data"];`. I want to append each of object in this array into txt file.

How can I do this?

My code is not working and I dont know why.

```
    $data = json_decode($data, true);

    foreach ($data as $v) {
        $myfile = file_put_contents('logs.txt', implode(" ", $v) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
```

With input `[{a: {b:[]}},{c: 'foo'}]` I am getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach.

Comment: print the output of `$myfile` to see what `file_put_contents()` returns

Comment: That is not valid json. You'll need to figure out your post submit of that json, as it will not `json_decode` as is. "quoted object property name expected"

Comment: With `[{"a": {"b":[]}},{"c": "foo"}]` - error - Array to string conversion

Comment: @vehumu `implode()` won't work with `{"a": {"b":[]}}`. The argument to `implode()` needs to be an array containing strings and/or numbers, but the element of this array is another array.

Comment: What are you expecting the log message to look like?

Comment: You cannot just randomly implode non-scalar items found within `$v`